# Set rxjs timer parameters values with condition

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a JS function in my angular app that uses rxjs.

```
executionCheck(): void {
  this.checkStatus = timer(5000, 25000)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.ngService.getData())
    ).subscribe(data => ...);
}
```

I would like to set `Timer` start delay dynamically.

that mean run a synchronous function that retuns true or false. if true set timer to 5000 otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
executionCheck(): void {
  this.checkStatus = timer(getTimerDelay(someValue), 25000)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.ngService.getData())
    ).subscribe(data => ...);
}

getTimerDelay(someValue): number {
  //your logic to return either 5000 or 0
  // for example:
  if(someValue /*some logical condition*/){ 
    return 5000;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```